# Find the number of rearrangements of the string 123456 in which none of the sequences 123, 321, 456, and 654 occur.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

My attempt:

> > Let $A_{1}$ denotes where 123 occurs, $A_{2}$ denotes where 321 occurs, $A_{3}$ denotes where 456 occurs, and $A_{4}$ denotes where 654 occurs. Also $|U|$=6!
> >
> > $$\begin{aligned}|A_{1} &\cup A_{2} \cup A_{3} \cup A_{4}|\\
> > &= |A_{1}|+|A_{2}|+|A_{3}|+|A_{4}|\\
> > &\quad -(|A_{1}A_{2}|+|A_{1}A_{3}|+|A_{1}A_{4}|+|A_{2}A_{3}|+|A_{2}A_{4}|+|A_{3}A_{4}|)\\
> > &\quad +|A_{1}A_{2}A_{3}|+|A_{1}A_{2}A_{4}|+|A_{1}A_{3}A_{4}|+|A_{2}A_{3}A_{4}|\\
> > &\quad-|A_{1}A_{2}A_{3}A_{4}|\\
> > =& \ ? \end{aligned}$$
> >
> > Then,
> >
> > $$\begin{aligned}|A_{1}'A_{2}'A_{3}'A_{4}'|& =|U|-|A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3} \cup A_{4}|\\
> > &= 6!-? \end{aligned}$$

I am pretty sure this is ALL wrong. Please help me with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You can have both 123 and 456 occurring ....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I think that they try to cover this possibility by subtracting $|A_{1}A_{3}|$, presuming that this is the number of times that both of those events occur.

Comment: Moreover, the first formula that they have written is just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: As for a hint, just use the formula! It looks daunting, but note that you can easily eliminating most of the terms because many of the sequences cannot occur at the same time e.g |A_{1}A_{2}| = 0 if this is when both 123 and 321 occur together.

Comment: You have set up the problem correctly.  Do you know how to find $|A_1|$?  Do you know which intersections are possible?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is quite  ok.

> We can enhance readability a bit by denoting the sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$    with
>   \begin{align*}
> A_{123},A_{321},A_{456},A_{654}
> \end{align*} 
>   instead. We  apply the *[IEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)*
>   and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> |A|&=6!-\left(|A_{123}|+|A_{321}|+|A_{456}|+|A_{654}|\right)\\
> &\qquad+\left(|A_{123}\cap A_{456}|+|A_{123}\cap A_{654}|+|A_{321}\cap A_{456}|+|A_{321}\cap A_{654}|\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> We  do not  have to respect more terms, since $$A_{123}\cap A_{321}=A_{456}\cap A_{654}=\emptyset$$
>
> Since $|A_{123}|=4!$ and $|A_{123}\cap A_{456}|=2!$ we get due to symmetry
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{|A|}&=6!-4\cdot4!+4\cdot 2!\\
> &=720-96+8\\
> &=\color{blue}{632}
> \end{align*}

Comment: You forgot to put "!" on the 6 in the finalized answer.

Comment: @Nixie777: Thanks! Typo corrected.